# Get list of mail not in Inbox (like Sent Mail)

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, outgoing-mail

Please forgive me if this has been answered already but I've been looking around for an answer to this but haven't been able to come up with anything usefull.

We migrated a number of pilot users to google apps for their mail (coming from exchange 2003). One of those users has a number of e-mails that only exist in his sent items folder in outlook/exchange. He usually 'archives' his sent items to a subfolder of Inbox. Anything that stays in his "sent items" folder in outlook are things he still needs to follow up on. After the migration we came to the conclusion that all of the mail 'archived' in this way showed up in his "sent mail" folder/label on his outlook google profile (it is also still in the 'archive' folder).

The result is that he now has a "sent mail" folder with a couple 1000 e-mails, about +90% of those are doubles that exists in one of his 'archive' folders as well. As there are probably a number of other users (that have not been migrated yet) that have the same way of 'archiving' I was looking at a way to automate the adding of a label to messages that are only in his sent items folder/label and nowhere else. I made a simple google script that looks for the label "sent" but this is where I ran into the issue that's been blocking me from getting this done. No mather what I try, the only mails that the script finds are mails in his Inbox (sub)folder, so the script doesn't find any mail that exists only under the "sent items" label. So my question: is there any way to get a google script to loop through this label/folder?

Answer (score 0):

Quick update:
I worked around this problem by doing some manual labour. I would still very much be interested in an answer to this should somebody have one.